# Count occurrences of values in second column equal to the given value in first column R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a following dataframe:

```
data_frame <- structure(list(position = c(10, 15, 10, 10, 25, 19, 25, 15, 20, 
31, 22, 20, 10, 19), length = c(21, 15, 19, 10, 27, 19, 25, 31, 
34, 31, 26, 27, 10, 19)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

I want to create the following dataframe from it:

```
data_frame2 <- structure(list(positionpositions = c(10, 15, 10, 10, 25, 19, 25, 15,  20, 31, 22, 20, 10, 19), lengthlengths = c(21, 15, 19, 10, 27, 19,  25, 31, 34, 31, 26, 27, 10, 19), desired_col1desired_col = c(2, 1, 2, 2,  1, 3, 1, 1, 0, 21, 0, 0, 2, 3), desired_col2 = c(2, 3, 2, 2, 8, 6, 8, 3, 6, 13, 7, 6, 2, 6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L))
```

where:

- "desired_col1" - informs of how many "lengths" are equal to the given value in column "position".
- desired_col2 - informs of how many "lengths" are equal to or lower than the given value in column "position".

I was trying multiple times, but could not apply the function column-wise.

EDIT: I was able to create the desired column 1 by converting the columns into vectors, using sum within sapply and adding the resulting vector as a new column. Like this:

```
x <- data_frame$position
y <- data_frame$length
counts <- sapply(x, function(val) sum(val == y))

data_frame$desired <- counts
```

However, I am still looking for something more straight-forward, a dplyr-based maybe.

Also I am still struggling with desired column 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
v <- df$length

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    desired_col1 = sum(v == position),
    desired_col2 = sum(v <= position)
  )
```

Results

```
# A tibble: 14 × 4
# Rowwise: 
   position length desired_col1 desired_col2
      <dbl>  <dbl>        <int>        <int>
 1       10     21            2            2
 2       15     15            1            3
 3       10     19            2            2
 4       10     10            2            2
 5       25     27            1            8
 6       19     19            3            6
 7       25     25            1            8
 8       15     31            1            3
 9       20     34            0            6
10       31     31            2           13
11       22     26            0            7
12       20     27            0            6
13       10     10            2            2
14       19     19            3            6
```

Answer (score 2):

I would get the count of each length element and then join that back to the original data:

```
library(dplyr)
data_frame %>%
  count(length) %>%
  rename(position = length) %>%
  left_join(data_frame, ., by = "position") %>%
  mutate(n = coalesce(n, 0))
#    position length n
# 1        10     21 2
# 2        15     15 1
# 3        10     19 2
# 4        10     10 2
# 5        25     27 1
# 6        19     19 3
# 7        25     25 1
# 8        15     31 1
# 9        20     34 0
# 10       31     31 2
# 11       22     26 0
# 12       20     27 0
# 13       10     10 2
# 14       19     19 3
```

Your `sapply` solution is quite good for base R, and more straightforward. Do note that "converting the columns into vectors" is skippable, the `sapply` can be done as a one-liner:

```
data_frame$desired = sapply(data_frame$position, \(x) sum(x == data_frame$length))
```

The `dplyr` solution with the join will be more efficient if your data is large.

Do be careful with your column names. Your two sample data frames and your code are quite inconsistent on `length` vs `lengths` and `positions` vs `position`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the perfect time for some combined mutate and 'lapply' usage!

```
data_frame %>% 
  mutate(count_col1 = sapply(position, function(x) sum(x == length)),
         count_col2 = sapply(position, function(x) sum(x >= length)))
```

[image]

Comment: I switched lapply to sapply so the result inserted into the column would not be a list. Some downstream functions may throw an error if they have assertions for vectors/integers not lists.